# Assign Value from Ajax to Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, leaflet

I have trouble to assign a value I am getting from the ajax call to an array and pass that array.

so the variable options is not valid

I have this code

```
$.ajax({ url: url,
    success: function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var object =  data[i];
            var array = JSON.parse(object.polygon);
            var options = {
                 color: object.color, 
                 fillColor: object.fill, 
                 fillOpacity: object.opacity
             };

            var options_example = {
                 color: "#fff", 
                 fillColor: "#000", 
                 fillOpacity: "0.7"
             };

            console.log(options);// This Print correctly
            console.log(options_example);// same as previous one

            var land = L.polygon(array,options).addTo(map);//Not Work
            var land = L.polygon(array,options_example).addTo(map);//Working
            land.bindPopup("<b>"+object.number+"</b><br>"+object.area);

        }
    }});
```

Response:

```
[{"id":"2","number":"asd","area":"asd","polygon":"[[32.31948848454971,35.31074523925781],[32.33022285080643,35.32121658325195],[32.318908212283944,35.360355377197266],[32.29743552506946,35.30954360961914],[32.31948848454971,35.31074523925781]]","basin":"asd","color":""},{"id":"7","number":"adasd","area":"asd","polygon":"[[32.32129727814492,35.36873459815979],[32.321542074502524,35.36865413188934],[32.32107061426081,35.36771535873413],[32.32083488321952,35.368616580963135],[32.32129727814492,35.36893308162689],[32.32134714412331,35.36882042884826],[32.32129727814492,35.36873459815979]]","basin":"asdas","color":"#fff","fill":"#000","opacity":"0.7"}]
```

I dont know what I am missing here

Comment: Can you post the sample response ?

Comment: on which line you are getting the error?? Response json will be more helpful if you can provide.

Comment: Updated, I added a response

Comment: I am not getting any error, the colors assigned is not write (options)

Comment: The properties that you are using to create `options` object doesn't exist on your first response. Have you updated those and tried ?

Comment: @ Peril what is `L.polygon` ??

Comment: @ozil It's a [leaflet API](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

In first element of array from response object doesn't have fields `fillColor` and `fillOpacity` and `color` is empty.

Maybe try some default vaules:

```
var options = {
             color: object.color || "#fff", 
             fillColor: object.fill || "#000", 
             fillOpacity: object.opacity || "0.7"
         };
```